# Strange Error in mysql_query() function in PHP (And clause in Query)

Tags: php, mysql

When I add AND operator in mysql_query() function, it stops working and anything after that stops working! 
For Example: 
When i wrote this:

```
 $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM chat1 where friendname = '$_POST[fname]' ");

 $row= mysql_fetch_array($query1) or die(mysql_error()); 
 echo "$row[message]";
```

The above query runs successfully !

But when i do this :

```
 $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM chat1 where friendname = '$_POST[fname]' AND username = '$_POST[uname]' ");

 $row= mysql_fetch_array($query1) or die(mysql_error()); 

 echo "$row[message]";
```

I get Null output!
I think the "AND" operator is not working!!!
please help me with this!!
Have a look at my complete code and Database Snapshot!
[Click here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4Vo_ku-aIKzflNXSlYybUNadDFSQ0lDcnBwcjZHdW5sTjVfV3lfRklNUGQ4U0FEVmZZZWs&usp=sharing)

Comment: mysql api is deprecated why you are not using mysqli or PDO??

Comment: What are your `$_POST` values? Again, use mysqli, and also try `echo mysqli_error();` so we can see an error...

Comment: change `friendname` = '{$_POST['fname']}'

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and you're probably getting null because your query didn't return any rows, so fetch_array returns boolean false, which you then try to use as an array.

Comment: My friends name is **Little Bobby Tables** [https://xkcd.com/327/](https://xkcd.com/327/).  The msyql interface is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO instead. Potentially unsafe values included in the text of a SQL statement *must* be properly escaped. But **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders** are a much better pattern.

Comment: you might be vulnerable to sql injections with that query

Comment: Right now i am not working on its security. I am just learning the basics! @Marc B why? I am getting null set when I add "AND" username=......... .         Take a look at my database attached to the link above!

Comment: because your `and` query doesn't match any rows. Check `mysql_num_rows()` and you'll undoutedly find it's `0`. A query which matches nothing is **NOT** an error. it's a perfectly valid result that happens to contain no rows.

Comment: @Marc B  But Sir,  record do exist (see the snapshot attached in the link! And both the values ( echo "$_POST[uname]"; and echo "$_POST[fname]"; are displaying "admin" and "user" respectively both present in database!

Comment: doesn't matter much, if they're not EXACT matches. e.g. `admin[space]` is not the same as `admin`. check `num_rows()`.

Comment: So what should i do to display that message by checking both username and password?

Answer (score 0):

If it is returning NULL then probably the record doesn't exists. Try to output this query on the screen and post the raw query here.

Maybe your search needs a **LIKE** instead of a **=**

Comment: No ! No record do exist (see the snapshot attached in the link!  And both the values (    echo "$_POST[uname]"; and echo "$_POST[fname]"; are displaying "admin" and "user" respectively both present in database!

Comment: ok, but you need to check the complete query to be sure that your script is outputing the right query. Try this: echo "SELECT *  FROM chat1 where friendname = '$_POST[fname]' AND username = '$_POST[uname]' ";
die;

Comment: I did this:   $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM chat1 where friendname= 'user' AND username= 'admin' ");    and got correct result .                Also  ( echo "$_POST[uname]"; and echo "$_POST[fname]"; are displaying "admin" and "user" )

Comment: Try this and see if works: mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM chat1 where friendname = '" . $_POST[fname] . "' AND username =  '". $_POST[uname] . "'");

Answer (score 0):

Likely, the row(s) you are looking for do not exist.

The `AND` is a boolean operator that requires that **both** expressions have to evaluate to true. In the context of your query, that means for a row to be returned, both of the conditions have to be true on that single row.

I suspect that you may want an `OR` those two conditions. Did you want to return only rows that meet both criteria, or did you want any rows that have `fname` with a certain value, along with any rows that have `uname` of a specific value? If the first query is returning rows, then replacing `AND` with `OR` should return you some rows.

---

For debugging this type of problem, generate the SQL text into a variable, and then echo or var_dump the SQL text, before you send it to the database.

e.g.

```
    $sql = "SELECT *  FROM chat1 where friendname = '" 
         . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname'])
         ."' ";
    echo "SQL=" . $sql ;  # for debugging
```

Take the text of SQL statement that's emitted to another client, to test the SQL statement, to figure out if the SQL statement is actually returning the resultset you expect it to return.

(In your code, reference the `$sql` in the function that prepares/executes the SQL statement.)

Follow this pattern for *all* dynamically generated SQL text:  generate the SQL text into a variable. For debugging, `echo` or `var_dump` or otherwise emit or log the contents of the variable. Take the SQL text to another client and test it.

Dumping code that isn't working on to StackOverflow is *not* the most efficient way to debug your program. Narrow down where the problem is.

[**How to debug small programs** http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

---

**NOTES**

You probably want to verify that `$_POST['fname'])` contains a value.

It's valid (SQL-wise) for a SELECT statement to return zero rows, if there are no rows that satisfy the predicates.

Potentially unsafe values *must* be properly escaped if you include them in the text of a SQL statement. (A better pattern is to use **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**, available in the (supported) mysqli and PDO interfaces.

Also, use single quotes around `fname`.... e.g.

```
    $_POST['fname']
           ^     ^
```